# Asp.Net Core LoggingProvider using Entity Framework Core reenters Log method

Tags: entity-framework, logging, asp.net-core

Using Asp.Net Core, and EF Core, I have the following issue trying to log to a DB:

I am trying to write a custom logging provider which logs to a DB using EF, however EF itself logs whenever savechanges is called, so the Log method is reentered. When it gets to savechanges in the reentrance, it throws an exception that the first operation hasn't completed, and then tries to log that exception, reentering the method again. This continues until I eventually get a stackoverflow. Can you think of a way around this?

Comment: I think one of the problems is how you would *expect* this to work? EF just writes its messages to a logger, it doesn't know where that will be written. If you were happy to only write Error `LogLevel` messages to the db then a solution may be possible, assuming that EF core doesn't ever write with that level!

Comment: I guess I'll have to stick with my workaround of checking for reentrance and breaking out.